# Vertical line does not show in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe which looks something like the following (for example):

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  category=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  daily_count=sample(18:100, n, replace=TRUE)
                  )
dat
#         date    category  daily_count
#1  2020-12-26        A          60
#2  2020-12-27        B          32
#3  2020-12-28        B          39
#4  2020-12-29        B          75
#5  2020-12-30        A          25
#6  2020-12-31        A          53
#7  2020-12-26        A          60
#8  2020-12-27        A          32
#9  2020-12-28        A          39
#10 2020-12-29        B          75
#11 2020-12-30        B          25
#12 2020-12-31        B          53
.
.
.
```

I am trying to create a boxplot with month and year on its X-Axis and it looks like this:
[image]

I would like to create a vertical line on ***2013-08-23***. I am using the following code for this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=daily_count,
                   x=reorder(format(dat$date,'%b %y'),dat$date),
                   fill=dat$category)) +
  xlab('Month & Year') + ylab('Count') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Category")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
         axis.title=element_text(size=10))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2013-08-23")), linetype=1, colour="red")
```

Any guidance please?

Comment: The issue is that `2013-08-23` lies outside of the range of dates on the x-axis, so it doesn't display.

Comment: @neilfws Thank you for your comment. What solution would you suggest? Because I'd like to draw the line at August 2013.

Comment: your request is not clear. here's my doubts: your reproducible example doesnt contain the date you requested: since you are creating a boxplot by MONTH, how can you show a vertical line on a DAY? can you please clarify your input and your expected result?

Comment: @Edo, my apologies for that. Yes, I want to show my boxplot by Month and I'd like to insert the line on August-2013. My MWE was just an example to show the kind of that I had. Actual data ranges between August-2012 to August-2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer:

- I've created a much bigger sample
- I'm using `yearmonth` from `tsibble` for simplicity
- I've solved the issue with the vertical line
- I cleaned up a bit the use of labs for a cleaner code

```r
set.seed(42)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2012-08-01"), as.Date("2014-08-30"), "day")
n <- length(dates)
dat <- data.frame(date = dates,
                  category = rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  daily_count = sample(18:100, n, replace=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = daily_count,
                   x = yearmonth(date),
                   group = paste(yearmonth(date), category),
                   fill = category)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept =  lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), linetype=1, colour="red", size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I set the vertical line thicker so to be seen.

---

Unfortunately the chart is difficult to visualize. Why don't you use ribbons instead?
With random data is horrible, but with yours you should see something meaningful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(category, yearmonth = yearmonth(date)) %>% 
  summarise(q = list(quantile(daily_count))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(q, names_sep = "_") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = yearmonth, fill = category, colour = category)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = `q_0%`, ymax = `q_100%`), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = `q_25%`, ymax = `q_75%`), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `q_50%`)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       colour = "Category",
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), linetype=1, colour="red", size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: one more question please. How can I show all months with their corresponding years on the x-axis?

Comment: just add `+ scale_x_yearmonth(date_breaks = "month")`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to do any "expansion"... This in NOT my solution, but a modified solution by @dario. I think the problem was in aesthetics.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y=daily_count,
                x=date,
                fill=category)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year', ylab= 'Count', fill = "Category") + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2020-12-28"), linetype=1, colour="red")
```